# Parsing strings that contain varied fields that are in varied orders in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, split, delimiter

I have some records:

```
records=['Event: Description of some sort of event, sometimes with a: colon 0 Date: 02/05/2008 Time: 9:30 am Location: Room A Result: Description of result 0',
    'Event: Description of event 1 ',
    'Event: Description of some sort of event 2 Date: 06/03/2010 Time: 1:30 pm Location: Room b Result: Description of result 2',
    'Date: 06/03/2010 Time: 2:30 pm  Event: Description of some sort of event 2 Result: Description of result 2 Location: Room b',
    'Date: 06/03/2010 Result: Description of result 3']
```

I (eventually) want to ingest them into a pandas dataframe, but I can't even figure out how to parse them into a useful list or dict. 
what I'm doing is:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
delimeters = ['Event:', 'Date:', 'Time:','Location:', 'Result:']
delimeters = '|'.join(delimeters)
print('without parentheses, I lose my delimeters:')
for record in records:
    print(re.split(delimeters, record))
```

I am curious why this generates an empty item at the start of each list. But more importantly I want to retain the delimiters.

I've seen examples that use parentheses around a single delimiter to keep it in the list of split strings, but this produces odd results with a concatenated list of possible delmeters. I don't understand, e.g., why adding parentheses produces Nones -- would love to understand that!

```
print('With parentheses things get wierd:')
delimeters = ['(Event:)', '(Date:)', '(Time:)','(Location:)', '(Result:)']
delimeters = '|'.join(delimeters)

for record in records:
    print(re.split(delimeters, record))
```

Ideally, I would extract the following as output of the parsing of a record:

```
{'Event': ['Description of some sort of event, sometimes with a: colon'], 
 'Date': ['02/05/2008'], 
 'Time': ['1:30 pm'], 
 'Location': ['Room b'],
 'Result': ['Some description of the result, sometimes with a : colon']} # etc
```

This would then give me the ability to pass directly to a dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Event': ['Description of some sort of event, sometimes with a: colon'], 
 'Date': ['02/05/2008'], 
 'Time': ['1:30 pm'], 
 'Location': ['Room b'],
 'Result': ['Some description of the result, sometimes with a : colon']} 
)
```

Any pointers or help on any step much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution without using regexes, though it does involve nested loops:

```
records = ['Event: Description of some sort of event, sometimes with a: colon 0 Date: 02/05/2008 Time: 9:30 am Location: Room A Result: Description of result 0',
    'Event: Description of event 1 ',
    'Event: Description of some sort of event 2 Date: 06/03/2010 Time: 1:30 pm Location: Room b Result: Description of result 2',
    'Date: 06/03/2010 Time: 2:30 pm  Event: Description of some sort of event 2 Result: Description of result 2 Location: Room b',
    'Date: 06/03/2010 Result: Description of result 3']

delims = ('Event:', 'Date:', 'Time:', 'Location:', 'Result:')

parsed = []

# Iterate records
for record in records:
    # An empty dictionary object
    d = {}
    # Split the record into separate words by spaces
    words = record.split(' ')
    # Iterate the words in the record
    for i in range(len(words)):
        # If this word is one of the delimiters
        if words[i] in delims:
            # Set the key to the delimiter (without a colon)
            key = words[i][:-1]
            # Increment the loop counter to skip to the next item
            i += 1
            # Start with a value of an empty list
            val = []
            # While we are inside the array bounds and the word is not a dilimiter
            while i < len(words) and not words[i] in delims:
                # Add this word to the value
                val.append(words[i])
                # Increment the loop counter to skip to the next item
                i += 1
            # Add the key/value pair to the record dictionary
            d[key] = ' '.join(val)
        # Append the record dictionary to the results
    parsed.append(d)


print(repr(parsed))
```

The idea is to split each record into a list of words and check to see if each one is a delimiter, setting it as a key if it is and adding the word to the value if it is not.

Output (pretty printed):

```
[{'Date': '02/05/2008',
  'Event': 'Description of some sort of event, sometimes with a: colon 0',
  'Location': 'Room A',
  'Result': 'Description of result 0',
  'Time': '9:30 am'},
 {'Event': 'Description of event 1 '},
 {'Date': '06/03/2010',
  'Event': 'Description of some sort of event 2',
  'Location': 'Room b',
  'Result': 'Description of result 2',
  'Time': '1:30 pm'},
 {'Date': '06/03/2010',
  'Event': 'Description of some sort of event 2',
  'Location': 'Room b',
  'Result': 'Description of result 2',
  'Time': '2:30 pm '},
 {'Date': '06/03/2010', 'Result': 'Description of result 3'}]
```

Comment: No problem! Just remember this solution requires the delimiters to be separated by spaces (as they seem to be in all of your data)